# Regression model syntax

Tags: regression, pca

this is also posted [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/regression-model-syntax) but I'm hoping some of the statistics experts can weigh in as well. It is a domain-specific question but heavily relevant to statistical methods as well.

I'm following the methodology outlined in [Developing High-Frequency Equities Trading Models](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/59122/658860705-MIT.pdf). On page 27, the author outlines an OLS regression model to obtain beta coefficients. The model is defined as:

$$r_{t+1} + ... + r_{t+H} = \beta_1\sum_{i=0}^HD_{t-i,1}+...+\beta_{k}\sum_{i=0}^HD_{t-i,k}+\eta_{t+H,H}$$

Where $r_{t+1} + ... + r_{t+H}$ is the accumulated $H$-period log return, $D=R^{T,k}$ is a $Txk$ matrix of dimentionally reduced log returns (principal components) obtained after projecting de-meaned log returns on the highest $k$ eigenvectors.

The author defines the process estimating $r_{t+1} + ... + r_{t+H}$ as such:

> We calculated the accumulated future $H$-period log returns. Then we ran a regression, estimated by OLS, on the future accumulate log returns with the last sum of $H$-period dimensionally reduced returns in the principal component space.

I'm struggling a bit to understand how to implement this model. I suppose where I am most confused is in the statement "We calculated the accumulated future $H$-period log returns." I can see clearly that the independent variables are the accumulated $H$-period dimentionally reduced log returns but I do not understand what the dependent variable would be in this case as we do not have future accumulated returns.

This is likely simply a question on syntax but one that has confused me in the past as well. So stated simply, what is the independent variable in this model upon which to train?

Comment: You'll need to read the papers that are referenced in this paper. It is probably best to hire a consultant to build this model for you if you're having trouble with vector notation.

Comment: Is that a joke?

Comment: @Maddenker: Does one of those papers deal with this specific question? And what makes you think the OP has difficulty with vector notation?

Comment: @strimp099: We should assume it's not a joke, merely rather cryptic.

Comment: To be clear, there is no question on the notation, rather how to train a model against returns the authors describe as "the accumulated future $H$-period log returns", operative word "future".